# page redirection in php long polling

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, long-polling

I am using php-long-polling to display data to user on instant basis in one of my projects. I got the script from here https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling
When counter sets to 1 it has to redirect to some other page. This redirection is not happening in **server.php** script.

```
ob_start();
set_time_limit(0);

include('includes/sessions.php');
while (true) {
    $last_ajax_call = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : null;
$id = $_GET['id'];

       $sql = "SELECT max(gid) FROM grp WHERE gid=".$id."";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($last_ajax_call == null || $last_change_in_data_file > $last_ajax_call) {
      $sql = "SELECT is_set, start FROM grp WHERE gid =".$id."";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


              if(($row['is_set'] == 1) && ($row['start'] == 1))
               {
//Here redirection should happen
$data .= "<script> window.location.href = './result.php?id=".$id."</script>";
}
}
}
```

I tried

```
header("location:result.php?id=$id");
exit();
```

But nothing did work. 
why these redirection not working.

Comment: please provide complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your PHP variable to this.  Setting sessions or cookies is in my opinion is the most secure way to transfer data with PHP.  Don't put sensitive info in a URL string.

```
header("location:result.php?id=".$id."");
exit();
```